# Integrating Whatsapp with Aws- for sending msgs about aws services

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, whatsapp

I'm looking for AWS integration with whatsapp.
when any user start the aws services , that should be notify on whatsapp
is there any youtube link, or reference available on the internet?
thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Whatsapp apis are not public.

To get the approval you need to give your application to facebook team [here](https://www.facebook.com/business/m/whatsapp/business-api)

But as far Facebook team is not directly approving the requests they are suggesting,

**In order to ensure a high quality experience for businesses and users, we're in a limited public preview.**

To go to market on WhatsApp Business API during this time, please consider using a Business Solution Provider. Facebook has partnered with over 46 global providers who specialize in WhatsApp business to consumer messaging. Search the [WA Business API provider directory now.](https://www.facebook.com/business/partner-directory/search?platforms=whatsapp&solution_type=messaging&sort_by=alpha)

Answer (score 0):

Good luck.. you can't rely on the consumer Whatsapp for an API (in fact they might ban your number if you try using one of the reverse engineered API on github).. but you can get the business API [here](https://www.whatsapp.com/business/api) .. if you can work out how to find the actual API spec.. you are probably better off to use something with a well established api connector to AWS though